# Flask, terminate running python function but do not terminate whole web server

Tags: python, flask, tcp

I have created a basic web app using python-flask. A user can upload a file for some analysis and some functions run at the back-end. When the job is done a file containing the results,is automatically sent to the user. However if the process runs so long, and the user tries to stop the operation, python functions still works at the back-end. I have to stop whole web app and re-run it to terminate python processes.

These are the processes on port 5000 when I run the web app.

```
$ lsof -i:5000

COMMAND  PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

python  5306 akinyilmaz    6u  IPv4 104621      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)

python  5309 akinyilmaz    6u  IPv4 104621      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)

python  5309 akinyilmaz    8u  IPv4 104621      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
```

When a client uploads a file and starts analyzing I get the following.

```
$ lsof -i:5000

COMMAND  PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

firefox 4276 akinyilmaz  106u  IPv4 145274      0t0  TCP akin_yilmaz.corp.airties.com:34274->akin_yilmaz.corp.airties.com:5000 (ESTABLISHED)

python  5306 akinyilmaz    6u  IPv4 110021      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)

python  5309 akinyilmaz    6u  IPv4 110021      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)

python  5309 akinyilmaz    8u  IPv4 110021      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)

python  5309 akinyilmaz    9u  IPv4 146944      0t0  TCP akin_yilmaz.corp.airties.com:5000->akin_yilmaz.corp.airties.com:34274 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I tried to get `PID`s and kill difference (which is 4276 in this case) but it actually did not work and python functions did not stop.
What can I do to kill only python functions running, but not to terminate whole web app?

Comment: why not use `celery` for `background processing`?

Comment: I am new to flask. Thank you for your comment. I will search how to use celery.